# How to change the Windows XP default language without reinstalling the OS

Tags: windows-xp, operating-systems, language

how can I change the Windows XP default language from French to US English without reinstalling the operating system?

If this is possible, how can I do this?

Comment: I think you cannot change the language in Windows XP. Maybe if you have the Professional version.

Answer (score 0):

MUI is an add-on to the English version of Windows XP Professional and Windows 2000 family of operating systems, and will not install on localized versions of Windows XP/2000 or on Windows XP Home Edition. So no, you can't change a French version of Windows XP to English.