# How to edit XP CD/ISO to change system and install process language

Tags: windows-xp, iso-image, language

Let's say we had our (for example) italian CD of WinXP, but now we can't find it, it's likely lost...
Now, a friend could lend us his XP CD (same channel, let's say "Home Edition" as an example), but he just own the English Home Ed. version.

Is there a way to edit/replace some file within the ISO in order to "translate" English Version XP CD to an Italian Version XP CD?
I'd like to obtain a system Italian localized as well as its install procedure.

Since I read it's possible to change windows license channel by editing some file within the iso, I thought it could be possible also for the language.

Comment: I don't know, but just to be clear.. Have you seen an XP installation completely in Italian?

Comment: See [How to change the Windows XP default language without reinstalling the OS](http://superuser.com/q/268779)

Comment: @DavidPostill just to be clear, your link "how to change"  is it suggesting there is an International version of XP where you can change it?

Comment: @barlop Not exactly, it suggests that you can't change the language if you have XP Home. You need Pro.

Comment: @DavidPostill an' international' pro, or any pro?

Comment: this is relevant https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb688178  though still doesn't answer how to or if you can convert xp Pro english into  international

Comment: @barlop You found the link I was looking for first ;) The Windows XP/2000 MUI is sold only through Volume Licensing programs such as the Microsoft Open License Program (MOLP/Open), Select, and Enterprise agreement (or with a new computer as an OEM version at customer request). It is not available through retail channels.

Comment: I suspect you can't even buy the MUI pack any more as XP is past end of life.